# Django Set Form Field Value In Post Request

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I am trying to set a form field value in views.py inside the Post request using data from request.session and then save that data to the db. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do that. Here is what I've tried:

```
    if self.form.is_valid():
        #attempt 1
        request.POST._mutable = True
        self.form.data['field'] = request.session['key']

        #attempt 2
        self.form.fields['field'] = request.session['key']

        #attempt 3
        self.form.cleaned_data['field'] = request.session['key']

        self.object = self.form.save()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

After trial and error I discovered that it is possible, but it has to be done outside the form validation statement. I did it like so:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.POST._mutable = True
    self.form.data['field'] = request.session['key']

    if self.form.is_valid():
        ........
```